# I am not able to refresh the app after login in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am performing login app functionality in my react native app but i am facing an issue that i am not able to get new  User data it requires me to kill my app and open it again to get the new data. i am using `async storage` to store my data can any one please help how to auto update the data after login in react native here is my code...

this is my `axios` call where i am performing login functionality...

```
 axios.post('https://.../wp-json/api/v1/user/do_login', {
        username: username,
        password: password
          })
          .then( async (response) => {
            if(response.data.type == "success"){
               this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');   
               await AsyncStorage.setItem('full_name', response.data.profile.pmeta.full_name);
               await AsyncStorage.setItem('user_type', response.data.profile.pmeta.user_type);
               await AsyncStorage.setItem('profile_img', response.data.profile.pmeta.profile_img);
               await AsyncStorage.setItem('profileBanner',response.data.profile.pmeta.banner_img)
               await AsyncStorage.setItem('profileType', response.data.type);
               await AsyncStorage.setItem('projectUid' , response.data.profile.umeta.id);
               await AsyncStorage.setItem('projectProfileId', response.data.profile.umeta.profile_id);


              //  NativeModules.DevSettings.reload();
            }else if(response.data.type == "error"){
              alert("Incorrect Detail");
            }
        })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
```

The issue is i am not getting the new user data in my home screen it requires kill app and start again to get new user data.... but i want that after login it automatically get new user data. please help

In my home screen i am getting the data here is the code...

```
export default class home extends React.Component {

  state = {
    data: [] , 
    default_color:'#fff',
    storedValue:'',
    storedType:'',
    profileImg:'',
    type:'',
    id:'',
    Pid:'',
  };


  componentWillMount() {
    this.getUser();
  }

  fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      BaseUrl + "list/get_categories"
    );
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({ data: json });
  };
  fetchFreelancerData = async () => {
    const Pid = await AsyncStorage.getItem('projectProfileId');
    console.log(Pid);
    const response = await fetch(
        BaseUrl + "listing/get_freelancers?listing_type=featured&profile_id=" + Pid 
    );
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({ fetchFreelancer: json });
  };
  fetchLatestPostedJobs = async () => {
    const Pid = await AsyncStorage.getItem('projectProfileId');
    const response = await fetch(
      BaseUrl + "listing/get_jobs?listing_type=latest"
    );
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({ fetchJobs: json });
  };
  _onPressButton =()=>{
  console.log('Hello');
  }
  _refresh =()=> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(()=>{resolve()}, 2000 )
    });
  }

  getUser = async() =>{
    try {
      const storedValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('full_name');
      const storedType = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user_type');
      const profileImg= await AsyncStorage.getItem('profile_img');
      const type = await AsyncStorage.getItem('profileType');
      const id = await AsyncStorage.getItem('projectUid');
      const Pid = await AsyncStorage.getItem('projectProfileId');
  //  console.log(storedValue ,storedType, profileImg  ,type , id);
      if(storedValue !== null){
         this.setState({storedValue})
      }else{
        // alert('something wrong')
      }


      if(storedType !== null){
        this.setState({storedType})
     }else{
      //  alert('something wrong')
     }

     if(profileImg !== null){
      this.setState({profileImg})
    }else{
      //  alert('something wrong')
    }

    if(type !== null){
      this.setState({type})
    }else{
      //  alert('something wrong')
    }
    if(id !== null){
      this.setState({id})
    }else{
    //  alert('something wrong')
    }
    if(Pid !== null){
      this.setState({Pid})
    }else{
    //  alert('something wrong')
    }
    this.fetchData();
    this.fetchFreelancerData();
    this.fetchLatestPostedJobs();

    } catch (error) {
      // Error saving data
      // alert(error)
    }
  }
```

Comment: you have to show how ur home screen obtains the data. where it is called.

Comment: I am getting the data in getUser  function

Comment: Looks valid. So your home component is mounted with the data. And when the api call succeeds, you need to `remount` the component as the code is executed only in `componentWillMount` or you need to maually re-initialize the component state after the api call succeeds.

Comment: can you please add a sample code it will be really helpfull

Comment: For that you need to show more data.. Where is the api call happening. Is it happening within `Home` or in diff component. If its in diff component, are you using some kind of state management or something.. ?

Comment: @Panther i am using Login screen component in which i am using axios call to login the user which i have mentioned above ... and after successful login i am moving to another screen called home .... and i am using Async Storage as state managment

Comment: why dn you just try to move `this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');   ` below all the `await async storage calls` and see if that helps

Comment: @Panther its not working i have tried it.